# Is bad design sign to return a lambda that breaks encapsulation

Tags: java, design-patterns, lambda, encapsulation

I have a `Game` class that needs some resources that are produced by `Generator`s classes.  Every game has its own  generators and because generators are heavy objects to instantiate, `Game` keeps an object pool with instances. In every Generator I have methods like these:

```
private MapBoardGenerator(Game game) {
    super(game);
}

public static MapBoardGenerator getInstance(Game game) {
    MapBoardGenerator instance = game.getGenerator(MapBoardGenerator.class);
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MapBoardGenerator(game);
        game.addGenerator(MapBoardGenerator.class, instance);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

This static method is almost identical in every class that extends `Generator`.

What I want to do is provide a `Supplier<MapBoardGenerator>` to `game` so the  controls will be made elsewhere and `getInstance` method will simply be:

```
public static MapBoardGenerator getInstance(Game game) {
    return game.getInstance(MapBoardGenerator.class, MapBoardGenerator::new);
}
```

Is something wrong if I pass a supplier that calls a private constructor? It's a university project and design matters a lot here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a private constructor as an instance of `Supplier` does not break encapsulation, for the very reason that the constructor is passed as an instance of `Supplier`. The receiver of the instance (in this case `Game`) has no idea how the `Supplier` is implemented, only that it fulfills the `Supplier` interface. That's what *Programming to an Interface* is all about: even though the caller provides a concrete implementation, the receiver is only aware of the interface which the implementation fulfills. Encapsulation would be violated if the `Game` knew the specific implementation that it was getting.

Note that passing a `Supplier` to the `Game` may or may not make sense in the larger context of your application, but at least it does not violate the encapsulation of `MapBoardGenerator`.

Comment: And what about circular references ?

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents : Maybe should you look at onion architectures. In onion architectures, your business (Game ?) is referenced by infrastructural components (Generators ?). This can imply lambda expressions injections (or delegates) from a Generator instance into Game instances to keep layers and responsabilities well separated.

I do not see why you should instanciate a new instance via reflection (for me that's a hack, but, as I come from C#, maybe is this remark not appropriate)...

Comment: I lambda a case of reflection?